# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1; in one environment but not another

Tags: java, spring

I am getting error - "Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1;" in one environment but not another.  The code is identical. The database is the same.
I checked path, environment variables, version, which, locate.
Code is below

```
    <bean id="stRulesExecutionReader"
                 class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader"                   scope="step">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="queryProvider">
<bean
                                  class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="selectClause"
value="select STID, RULEID, ITMVALSTR, ITMBSNSTR,SLS_TTY_RL_EFF_TS, SLS_TTY_RL_XPRY_TS,RULE_DLT_IND  " />
<property name="fromClause" value="from MDM_EXTEND.STRULES_FETCH_CRITERIA" />
<property name="whereClause" value=" WHERE ITMVALSTR IS NOT NULL AND (PROCESSED !='Y' OR PROCESSED IS NULL) AND ( NVL(RULE_SUCCESS,'NULL')!='MANUAL'  AND (RULE_SUCCESS IS NULL OR RULE_SUCCESS IN (SELECT DECODE(to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DY'),'SAT','WEEKEND','SUN','WEEKEND',null) FROM DUAL))) " />
<property name="sortKey" value="RULEID" />
</bean>
</property>
<property name="pageSize" value="10" />
<property name="rowMapper">
```

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: That's not code...

Comment: That's the xml code but it spaced it strange.

Comment: Don't know what happened to it

Comment: I can't seem to get the code posted. Says it's too long